# Send python object with Kafka

Tags: python, apache-kafka, microservices

I'm working on a distributed project and I need to send a python object from one microservice to another. I'm using kafka as communication system and I want to send a message like this with a kafka producer:

```
self.producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers=self.config.get('kafka').get('bootstrap_servers'),
                                  value_serializer=lambda m: json.dumps(m).encode('utf-8'))
data = {'message': {
        'action': 'new_service_order',
        'service_order': ServiceOrder(_service_order_id, _creation_ts, 0, order_items)
    }, 'metadata_type': MessageType.notify_monitor.name}


    self.producer.send('MONITOR', data)
```

Unfortunately I can't read this message in a consumer:

```
consumer = KafkaConsumer(
'MONITOR',
bootstrap_servers=['172.1.1.3:9094'],
auto_offset_reset='earliest',
enable_auto_commit=True,
group_id='my-group',
value_deserializer=lambda m: json.loads(m.decode('utf-8')))

while True:
for message in consumer:
    message = message.value
    print('Received {}'.format(message))
```

I tried different ways to serialize / deserialize the message changing 'value_deserializer' parameter (like mgspack and pickle) but the consumer was not able to read the message anyway.

Of course if I remove 'service_order' field everything works perfectly, then I think the problem is the object serialization.

What is the best way to exchange objects with kafka?

Comment: What exactly is the error? Don't you get any message or are just not able to deserialize it?

Comment: Are you actual able to store a serialized data object to a local file (using the lambda you have as a value_serializer) and then load it using the value_deserializer?

Comment: I can't receive the message on consumer side. I can save the message in a local file. The problem is exchanging messages with python objects with kafka.

Comment: Are you able to read the raw message via the kafka-console-consumer.sh script? If not, then the problem may be with your producer.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I'll try it tomorrow morning.

Comment: The problem seems due to the serialization of the object, if I pass an object similar to a dictionary everything work well. It's very strange, I'll continue to work on it.

Comment: Ok I found the solution, the problem was with python object serialization. If you have any object you want to convert to json for exchanging with kafka, you have to explicitly call the attribute __ dict __.

Comment: Has anyone achieved this?  I'm facing a similar problem.